# How to import ResourceDictionary from another project in Xamarin.Forms with Prism?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, prism

I have two projects:

- **ProjectOne** has a *ResourceDictionary* with some styles, on /Styles/DefaultStyle.xaml.
- **ProjectTwo** has a reference to **ProjectOne** (Right clic on **ProjectTwo**, Add... > Project Reference)

On `App.xaml` I tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
             x:Class="ProjectB.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectOne;component/Styles/DefaultStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

But I receive the followid error:

```
Invalid URI: Invalid port specified
```

What I am doing wrong? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
             xmlns:project2Resources="clr-namespace:Project2.Resources"
             x:Class="ProjectB.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <project2Resources:FileName />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

Note:- Untested code