# How to access style defined in global resource dictionary using code in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I have defined style in Styles.xaml file like:

```
<Style
     x:Key="LabelFiledVerticalStyle"
     TargetType="Label">   
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,7,0,0" />
</Style>
```

#### Way 1

I want to access it from my code behind file, so I have did this:

```
var LabelStyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["LabelFiledVerticalStyle"];
```

When I run the app it gives this error:
The resource "LabelFiledVerticalStyle" is not present in the dictionary

#### Way 2 Access resources by key from code

I have go through official documentation provided by Microsoft and I have found other way to do it.  So, did try that as well like:

```
var hasValue = Resources.TryGetValue("LabelFiledVerticalStyle", out object style);
if (hasValue)
{
    var LabelStyle = (Style)style;
}
```

In this also I'm getting hasValue = false though the style is there in Resource dictionary.

Does someone know how we can access it from code behind? Please let me know.

Comment: Where are you when you access Resources?

Comment: Hover over Resources, and tell me if you see Application.Resources or VisualElement.Resources.

Comment: Application.Current.Resources?

Comment: Are you sure? This should be working 100%. Please change it to the whole name, Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue. Just to be sure...

Comment: Waaaaaaaaaaait. When do you do this? Is the app already initialized? Just show me the whole file.

Comment: Yes, app is already initialized. The issue is merge dictionary part is not working. Because when debugging the code it shows MergedDictionary count = 0

Comment: So can you show the xaml code for merging the dictionary? Where in your app.xaml are you merging your Styles.xaml file?

Comment: @Divyesh_08 Show me your whole file where you call this: var hasValue = Resources.TryGetValue("LabelFiledVerticalStyle", out object style);

Answer (score 0):

**For the first way**

If you want to access the style with the first way, we usually define the styles in file `App.xaml`

For example, we can define styles in `App.xaml` as follows:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Styles.App">
      <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
            
                  <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" 
                        Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" 
                        Value="CenterAndExpand" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderColor"
                        Value="Lime" />
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" 
                        Value="5" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderWidth" 
                        Value="5" />
                        <Setter Property="WidthRequest"
                        Value="200" />
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" 
                        Value="Teal" />
                  </Style>
            
            <!-- ContentPage -->
            <Style TargetType="ContentPage"
                   ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                        Value="WhiteSmoke" />
            </Style>

            <!--define the style of Label  here-->

            <Style x:Key="LabelFiledVerticalStyle"  TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,7,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" 
                        Value="Red" />
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
      </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then in our page,we can access the style with code:

```
new Label { Text="test label",Style=(Style)Application.Current.Resources ["LabelFiledVerticalStyle"]}
```

A usage example:

```
public class ApplicationStylesPageCS : ContentPage 
      {
            public ApplicationStylesPageCS ()
            {
                  Title = "Application";
                  IconImageSource = "csharp.png";
                  Padding = new Thickness (0, 20, 0, 0);

                  Content = new StackLayout {
                        Children = {
                              new Button { Text = "These buttons", Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources ["buttonStyle"] },

                              new Label { Text="test label",Style=(Style)Application.Current.Resources ["LabelFiledVerticalStyle"]}
                        }
                  };
            }
      }
```

For more information, you can check document [Global Styles in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application).

**For the second way**

If you create a `ResourceDictionary`(for example `MyResourceDictionary.xaml`) and add your style to the `ResourceDictionary`,just as follows:

`MyResourceDictionary.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
   
    <!--define the style of Label  here-->

    <Style x:Key="LabelFiledVerticalStyle"  TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,7,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" 
                        Value="Red" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then if we want to access the style, we should add above `ResourceDictionary`  to the `ContentPage.Resources` of our page.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <!--add your ResourceDictionary here-->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />
    
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

You can refer to the sample code here:

`ApplicationStylesPage.xaml`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Styles.ApplicationStylesPage" Title="Application" IconImageSource="xaml.png">
      <ContentPage.Resources>
        <!--add your ResourceDictionary here-->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />
        
        <ResourceDictionary>
                  <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Lime" />
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="5" />
                        <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="200" />
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
                  </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
      </ContentPage.Resources>
      <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout Padding="0,20,0,0">

                  <Button Text="application style overrides" Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
            </StackLayout>
      </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

`ApplicationStylesPage.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class ApplicationStylesPage : ContentPage 
      {
            public ApplicationStylesPage ()
            {
                  InitializeComponent ();
            }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var hasValue = Resources.TryGetValue("LabelFiledVerticalStyle", out object style);
            if (hasValue)
            {
                var LabelStyle = (Style)style;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The resource dictionary I'm trying to access comes from a different project. Which is not working.

Comment: We cannot access codes from a different project differently. But you can try to add preference to another project by right clicking your project. Check [How to import ResourceDictionary from another project in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937179/how-to-import-resourcedictionary-from-another-project-in-xamarin-forms-with-pris).

Answer (score 0):

I went through a similar problem and the solutions were quite helpful with one caveat:

In a regular Maui app, the resources will not be on Resources but in App.Current.Resources, if at first the afore solutions don't work, use this one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35766802)